# Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний элемент

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, перегрузка-операторов, шаблоны-с++

Создаю шаблон класса для массива

файл **myArray.h**

```
#ifndef myArray_h
#define myArray_h

#include <iostream>
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

template <typename T> class myArray //создание шаблона класса myArray
{
    T** mas; //указатель на двумерный массив
    int line, //кол-во строк
        column; //кол-во столбцов

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, const myArray& el)
    //перегрузка оператора вывода >>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < el.line; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < el.column; j++)
            {
                in >> el.mas[i][j];
            }
        }

        return in;
    }

  public:
    myArray()
    {
        mas = 0;    //конструктор без параметров
        line = 0;
        column = 0;
    }
    myArray(int n, int m); //прототип конструктора с параметрами
    myArray(const myArray& masToCopy); //прототип конструктор копирования

    ~myArray() //деструктор
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {
            delete[](mas[i]);
        }

        delete[](mas);
    }
    friend myArray <T> operator +(const myArray<T>&, const myArray<T>&);
    //прототип перегрузки оператора сложения +
};

template <typename T> myArray <T>::myArray(int n = 1, int m = 1)
    : line(n),    column(m) //конструктор с параметрами
{
    mas = new int* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
}
template <typename T> myArray <T>:: myArray(const myArray& masToCopy)
// конструктор копирования
{
    line = masToCopy.line;
    column = masToCopy.column;
    mas = new int* [line];  // для новой копии

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        mas[i] = new int[column];

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            mas[i][j] = masToCopy.mas[i][j];
}

template <typename T> myArray <T>  operator+(const myArray<T>& m1,
        const myArray<T>& m2)
//перегрузка оператора сложения +
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.column; j++)
        {
            m1.mas[i][j] = m1.mas[i][j] + m2.mas[i][j];
        }
    }

    return m1;
}
```

файл **main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "myArray.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    myArray<int> intArray1(2, 2);
    myArray<int> intArray2(2, 2);
    myArray<int> A = intArray1 + intArray2;
    cout << A;
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку
[image: ошибка]

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То объявление friend-функции `operator +`, которое вы сделали, ссылается на *нешаблонную* функцию с параметрами `myArray<T>` для каждого варианта вашего шаблона `myArray<T>`. То есть в вашем конкретном примере другом для класса `myArray<int>` объявлена обычная нешаблонная функция

```
myArray<int> operator +(const myArray<int> &, const myArray<int> &);
```

Именно эта функция является самым лучшим кандидатом для вызова при вычислении `intArray1 + intArray2`. Именно эту функцию будет пытаться вызвать компилятор. Но так как такой функции у вас в коде нигде не определено, возникнет ошибка.

Если вы хотите, чтобы для класса `myArray<T>` другом была именно конкретная специализация определенного вам ниже *шаблона* функции `operator +`, вам надо объявить другом вашего класса *именно этот шаблон*. Для чего придется использовать несколько другой подход и синтаксис.

Во-первых, необходимо объявить шаблон функции `operator +` *заранее* (еще до определения вашего класса)

```
template <typename T> class myArray;
template <typename T> myArray<T> operator +(const myArray<T> &, const myArray<T> &);
```

Во-вторых, после этого в friend-объявлении внутри определения класса следует сослаться на этот шаблон при помощи синтаксиса с `<>` после имени функции

```
template <typename T> class myArray
{
  ...
  friend myArray<T> operator +<>(const myArray<T> &, const myArray<T> &); 
};
```

---

Функции-члены шаблонов классов сами являются шаблонами. Язык С++ запрещает "добавление" аргументов по умолчанию в повторных объявлениях шаблонов функций. (Такое возможно только для обычных нешаблонных функций.) Все аргументы по умолчанию должны присутствовать в самом первом объявлении шаблона функции.

В вашем случае, если вы хотите использовать аргументы по умолчанию в конструкторе

```
template <typename T> myArray<T>::myArray(int, int)
```

эти аргументы должны быть указаны сразу, прямо в объявлении этого конструктора внутри определения класса. "Дописать" аргументы по умолчанию позже нельзя. У вас же аргументы по умолчанию указаны позже - в определении этой шаблонной функции. Это не компилируемо в С++. Поэтому как вы умудрились добраться до ошибки линковки с этим кодом, который вообще не компилируется (в т.ч. и из-за других ошибок) мне не ясно.

На SO рекомендуется приводить реальный код, а не ложные выдумки "по мотивам".

Comment: Что-то у вас слишком сложно, нет? Вполне достаточно просто правильно объявить друга - как     `template<typename U>
    friend myArray <U> operator +(const myArray<U>&, const myArray<U>&);`

Comment: @Harry: Во-первых, я - за педантичную точность. Во-вторых, моя цель не сводится к банальному "исправить как-нибудь, чтобы скомпилировалось", а в объяснении того, как работает эта фича языка. В предложенном вами варианте получится что все `+` являются друзьями всех `myArray`. Т.е. оператор сложения для `myArray<double>` будет другом для класса `myArray<SomeClass>` и т.д. и и т.п  в любых комбинациях.

Comment: А язык С++ позволяет вам ограничиться лишь "точной" дружественностью: оператор сложения для  `myArray<int>` является другом только для `myArray<int>` (я уверен, что в этом и заключалось намерение автора). Но для этого надо предпринять ряд дополнительных телодвижений. Хочет ли автор тратить эти дополнительные усилия или не хочет - это уже вопрос отдельный.

Comment: Все пытаюсь придумать, как злоупотребить тем, что `+` будет другом для всех `myArray`. Никак не могу сообразить, как это может оказаться опасным, не подскажете? Только без вариантов в реализации преднамеренно использовать разные типы массивов, например `myArray<int>` и `myArray<double>`.

Comment: @Harry: Во-первых, я не совсем понимаю логики выбора фичи языка на основе того, можно или нельзя ей "злоупотребить". (Злоупотребить-то не сложно - вы сами привели пример.) Но, во-вторых, речь совсем не о подавлении попыток злоупотреблений, а просто о способе точно выразить авторское намерение. Я хочу (и мне достаточно того), чтобы другом моего `myArray<int>` был именно и только `operator +<int>`. Это вполне естественное желание. Именно это нам нужно. Мой ответ показывает, как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Более того, иногда можно услышать мнение (не лишенное рационального зерна), что полагаться на ADL тем, кто еще не совсем хорошо представляет, что это такое - не самая лучшая идея. То есть не стоит полагаться только на "скрытые" объявления функции, сделанные через friend-объявления внутри классов, а лучше все таки добавить нормальное объявление на уровне namespace. А та якобы "сложность", которую вы усмотрели в моем варианте только к этому фактически и сводится.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, у вас не объявлен оператор `operator <<`. Поэтому данное предложение

```
cout << A;
```

является ошибочным.

Во-вторых, У вас конфликтуют конструкторы, так как вы перестарались с аргументами по умолчанию. В связи с этим компилятор будет не способен выбрать правильный конструктор.

Вы могли бы объявить конструкторы следующим образом

```
myArray() : mas( 0 ), line( 0 ), column( 0 ) {} //конструктор без параметров
myArray(int n, int m); //прототип конструктора с параметрами
```

И для второго конструктора не указывать в его определении аргументы по умолчанию.

Что касается оператора `operator +`, то следует его объявить в классе как шаблонную функцию. Например,

```
template <typename U>
friend myArray <U> operator +(const myArray<U> &, const myArray<U> &);
```