# Как избежать реализации методов класса рядом с функцией main?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, clion

В чем заключается проблема:

Работаю в С++ с классами, создаю ClassName.cpp и ClassName.h
Пишу прототипы методов в .h файле, реализую в .срр, но ничего не работает, выдает ошибку:

//моя среда разработки - CLion

```
"D:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\cmake-build-debug --target StudyProj -- -j 2
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable StudyProj.exe
CMakeFiles\StudyProj.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::LinkedList()'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::append(int)'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::append(int)'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::append(int)'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::output()'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::~LinkedList()'
D:/workspaceForCLion/StudyProj/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::~LinkedList()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\StudyProj.dir\build.make:173: recipe for target 'StudyProj.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'StudyProj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [StudyProj.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [StudyProj] Error 2
```

НО, если я реализую в файле main.cpp все методы, а файл "ClassName.cpp" пусть - все отлично работает.

**Собственно, в чем вопрос - как реализовать методы в .cpp файле, не мейн, чтобы они работали?**

*И еще проблема с реализацией перегрузки операции " << ", кто знает, как можно вывести через перегрузку операции линейный список - подскажите.
Я пытался реализовать friend функцию, но всегда выдавало ошибки, пришлось выводить через метод "output".*

Сам проект:

LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    typedef unsigned int ui;

    template<class T>
    class LinkedList {
    private:
        struct node {
            T data;
            node *next;
        } *head;
    public:
        LinkedList();

        ~LinkedList();

        void append(T data);

        void prepend(T data);

        void remove(T data);

        void clear();

        void output();
    };
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    head=NULL;
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    node *p, *q;
    p = head;
    if(p==NULL) return;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::prepend(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head == NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        if(p->data == data){
            q->next = p->next;
            delete p;
            return;
        }
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        if(q != head){
            head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        p = q;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    p = head;
    while(p->next!=NULL)
        p = p->next;
    q = new node;
    q->data = data;
    q->next = NULL;
    p->next = q;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::output() {
    node *p;
    p = this->head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        std::cout << p->data << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    LinkedList<int> mylist;
    mylist.append(1);
    mylist.append(2);
    mylist.append(3);

    mylist.output();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Реализация всех методов в main.cpp

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    head=NULL;
};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    node *p, *q;
    p = head;
    if(p==NULL) return;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::prepend(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head == NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        if(p->data == data){
            q->next = p->next;
            delete p;
            return;
        }
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL) return;
    p = head;
    while(p){
        q = p->next;
        delete p;
        if(q != head){
            head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        p = q;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T data){
    node *p, *q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    p = head;
    while(p->next!=NULL)
        p = p->next;
    q = new node;
    q->data = data;
    q->next = NULL;
    p->next = q;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::output() {
    node *p;
    p = this->head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        std::cout << p->data << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    LinkedList<int> mylist;
    mylist.append(1);
    mylist.append(2);
    mylist.append(3);

    mylist.output();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема с перегрузкой "<<":

добавил др функцию:(пространство имен std определено ранее в .h файле, сама функция реализована и объявлена в нем же)

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkedList<T> &s);

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkedList<T> &s){
    if(s.head == NULL){
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
        return os;
    }
    node *p;
    p = s.head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->data << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> "D:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\cmake-build-debug --target StudyProj --
>   -j 2 [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj In file included from D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\main.cpp:2:0:
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\LinkedList.h:29:65: warning: friend
>   declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, LinkedList&)'
>   declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkedList &s);
>                                                                    ^ D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\LinkedList.h:29:65: note: (if this is
>   not what you intended, make sure the function template has already
>   been declared and add <> after the function name here) 
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\LinkedList.h: In function
>   'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, LinkedList&)':
>   D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\LinkedList.h:130:5: error: 'node' was
>   not declared in this scope
>        node *p;
>        ^~~~ D:\workspaceForCLion\StudyProj\LinkedList.h:130:11: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
>        node *p;
>              ^ mingw32-make.exe[3]:*  [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1 mingw32-make.exe[2]:
>    *[CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]:*  [CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe: *
>   [StudyProj] Error 2 CMakeFiles\StudyProj.dir\build.make:61: recipe for
>   target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/all' failed CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe
>   for target 'CMakeFiles/StudyProj.dir/rule' failed Makefile:117: recipe
>   for target 'StudyProj' failed

Comment: Определения шаблонных методов должно быть в заголовочном файле там же, где определен шаблонный класс.

Comment: Это всегда так? Так сказать, правило?

Comment: Да. Любая единица компиляции должна иметь определение шаблонных методов, чтобы вывести их конкретное определение. Это делается на этапе компиляции, а не на этапе редактирования связей.

Comment: Благодарю!
А что с перегрузкой оператора "<<"?
Как её реализовать?

Comment: Объявите дружественную шаблонную функцию и определите ее в заголовочном файле.

Comment: добавил др функцию, но "выскакивает" ошибка(Добавил к посту код и лог ошибки в конец)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите использовать шаблоны "естественным" образом, т.е. чтобы они сами по мере необходимости автоматически инстанциировались с вашими шаблонными аргументами (*неявное инстанциирование* шаблона `LinkedList` с аргументом `int` в вашем случае), то полное определение шаблонов должно быть видно в том месте, в котором они используются. В случае шаблона класса, это относится как к самому шаблону класса, так и к шаблонам его методов.

Это значит, что поместить определения шаблонов методов вы можете в какой угодно файл. Однако файл с определением методов вам тоже придется *включать* во все файлы, где используются эти методы, как обычный заголовочный файл. Т.е. в вашем случае вы можете поместить определения методов в `LinkedList.cpp`, если вам так хочется, но затем вам придется всегда *включать* это файл рядом с `LinkedList.h`, вместо того, чтобы компилировать `LinkedList.cpp` отдельно

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "LinkedList.cpp"
```

(или вообще сразу поместить `#include "LinkedList.cpp"` внутрь `LinkedList.h`). То есть такое разделение на файлы будет чисто условным, ничего с точки зрения процесса компиляции не достигающим. Такое, тем не менее, практикуется. Однако давать такому файлу расширение `.cpp` не рекомендуется - это все таки *включаемый* файл, а не независимая единица трансляции.

Обойти это требование можно только отказавшись от автоматического инстанциирования шаблона и перейдя на "ручное" инстанциирование (т.наз. *явное инстанциирование*). В вашем случае можно оставить все как есть, но просто добавить в файл `LinkedList.cpp` строчку

```
template class LinkedList<int>;
```

и все должно начать корректно компилироваться даже с независимо транслируемым файлом `LinkedList.cpp`. Однако необходимость ручного инстанциирования шаблона для всех комбинаций шаблонных аргументов делает такой способ неприменимым на практике (да и не для этого явное инстанциирование предназначено). Поэтому не стоит применять явное инстанциирование без необходимости, а лучше просто поместить все определение шаблона прямо в один заголовочный файл и полагаться на то, что компилятор для вас все сам правильно инстанциирует.

---

Что же касается неправильного объявления friend-оператора, ситуация подробно разбиралась здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641338/182825

Answer (score 0):

Если единственная инстанциация шаблона с данными параметрами есть в main.cpp, то никак. Можно использовать `extern template LinkedList<int>` чтобы избежать повторной инстанциации,  если `LinkedList<int>` использовался в другом модуле, но при использовании шаблона его описание должно быть полным. Некоторые программисты, работающие с MS Visual C++, считают это extern позволяет достать реализацию шаблона из .cpp, но на самом деле просто отдельные версии мекломягкого компилятора имеет расширенное поведение, когда создание шаблонов *возможно* на этапе связывания.
Иногда заголовок делят на файл с описанием шаблона класса и файл с описанием методов шаблона, если это нужно для обеспечения переносимости или других форм условной компиляции.

Comment: Это какая-то смесь домыслов. Во-первых, явная инстанциация шаблонов - стандартная фича языка С++. Синтаксис явной инстанциации - `template class LinkedList<int>;` присутствовал в языке всегда. Начиная с С++11 такая явная инстанциация может использоваться в паре с предварительным объявлением `extern template cass LinkedList<int>;`. Это действительно позволяет избежать повторной инстанциации. Никакого "расширения компилятора" в этом нет. Никакого "создания шаблонов на этапе связывания" (?) тут нет тоже - это вы уже, похоже, придумали сами.

Comment: Во-вторых, ваше `extern template LinkedList<int> mylist` - это какая-то синтаксическая каша, никаким из известных мне компиляторов не поддерживаемая. В-третьих, использование "пионэрско-ламерского" сленга на уважаемом сайте не придаст ответу веса.

Comment: @AnT MS Visual studio позволяет  не  включать реализацию в  заголовок,  на практике, код ОП  там сработал бы (работало в VC6 VC2003, VC2005, 2008, позже не пробовал) без ошибки . как ни смешно, то , на что вы разъярились - обычная опечатка, вызванная autocomplete. И о каком сленге речь? Если вы из другой культурной линии, не спешите обливать  грязью других. К примеру за слово "инстанциация" в тексте у меня на работе можно получить ( и не пирожок). А  "связывание" никто не понимает, используют "линковку". И то крупнейший концерн ВПК :P

Comment: @AnT Причем VC6 и VС2003 ваше "присутствовал в языке всегда" не понимали. Приходилось делать макропределение которое бы создавало перемнную такого типа в случае компиляции под ними, т.к. template class LinkedList<int>; эти компиляторы не понимали

Comment: Нет, MSVS не позволяет и никогда не позволял не включать реализацию в заголовок. Такая попытка приведет лишь к пресловутому LNK2009, которым забит весь интернет в том числе именно по этой причине. И нет, код ОП в  MSVS не будет компилироваться (именно с LNK2009). Если вы хотите рассказать про "создание переменной такого типа" как один из способов вызвать явное инстанциирование - то это, как ни странно, работает практически во всех компиляторах (по понятным причинам). Однако синтаксис такого объявления переменной вы привели неправильно, поэтому было не ясно, что вы пытались сделать.

Comment: Это тем не менее не отменяет того факта, что вместо объявления какой-то переменной можно было просто воспользоваться явной инстанциированием. Да, там когда-то были какие-то подводные камни в MSVS, но это не повод для того, чтобы выстраивать на этом какие-то монументальные теории. А под "пионэрско-ламерским" дворовым сленгом я имел в виду слово "мелкомягкие". Это у вас autocomplete так поработал  - тогда, конечно, другое дело...

Comment: @AnT ну, у нас в  репозитоии как минимум были две ревизии, которые правила эту ошибку, так как программист сделал именно это и на GCC не проверил. Речь о компиляторе 200го года, там конечно могли быть проблемы. И тут же выяснили что явная инстанциация не поддерживалась тоже. А кое-кого из "старожилов" приходится все время одергивать (к нам другие отделы присоединили, которые писали только для Windows). А синтаксис "выскочил" как результат слишком умного autocomplete, который запомнил это слово   mylist из другого окна

Comment: @AnT Насчет "мелкомягкие" - возможно, согласен, но я еще не встретил ни одного программиста, который бы не назвал  Microsoft так. Происхождение вовсе не ламерское. Причем источником  является не только известная шутка, а так же литературное произведение, где название компьютерной  мега корпорации было Littlesoft. Кое-кто этим воспользовался и создал корпорацию "Littlesoft Co.", но им пришлось переименоваться в "The Little Software Co."