# Перегрузка шаблонных операторов с разделением на описание и имплементацию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс `Vector2<T>`, шаблонный.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
public:
    // ...
    friend Vector2<T> operator*(ConstAddress<Vector2<T>> l_v, ConstAddress<T> r_val);
    // ...
}

// ...

template<typename T>
Vector2<T> operator*(ConstAddress<Vector2<T>> l_v, ConstAddress<T> r_val)
{ return Vector2<T>(l_v._x * r_val, l_v._y * r_val); }
```

`ConstAddress<T>` - это моё собственное извращение, но в целом это то же самое, что и `const T&`.

При попытке скомпилировать выдаёт ошибку

> undefined reference to `operator*(Vector2 const&, float const&)'

Comment: Скажите, а определение (второй скрин) у вас в том же хедере, что и `class Vector2`? Или в .cpp файле?

Comment: В инлайне (.inl), который подключён в конце хеадера

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Тема всплывает с заметной периодичностью.)

В качестве "друга" вы объявили *нешаблонную* функцию `operator *`. А определение ваше сделано для *шаблона* функции `operator *` - оно к вашему "другу" никакого отношения не имеет. Для оператора-друга вы не предоставили определения вообще, а именно его и пытается вызвать компилятор. Получается ошибка линковки.

(Если вы заставите компилятор вызвать именно шаблонную версию оператора, определенную после класса, то вы наткнетесь на другую ошибку: "другом" эта версия оператора не является и доступа к внутренним полям класса не имеет.)

- Либо объявите *шаблон* функции в качестве "друга"

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class Vector2
  {
    ...
    template <typename U> 
    friend Vector2<U> operator *(ConstAddress<Vector2<U>> l_v, ConstAddress<U> r_val);
    ...
  };

  template <typename T>
  Vector2<T> operator *(ConstAddress<Vector2<T>> l_v, ConstAddress<T> r_val)
    { return Vector2<T>(l_v._x * r_val, l_v._y * r_val); }
  ```
- Либо перенесите определение вашего оператора прямо в тело класса - чтобы оно определяло правильную *нешаблонную* функцию. (Если я не ошибаюсь, синтаксиса для того, чтобы сделать это за пределами класса в С++ просто нет.)

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class Vector2
  {
    ...
    friend Vector2<T> operator *(ConstAddress<Vector2<T>> l_v, ConstAddress<T> r_val)
      { return Vector2<T>(l_v._x * r_val, l_v._y * r_val); }
    ...
  };
  ```

В первом случае вы получите то, что я называю "ленивым" набором объявлений - все версии шаблонного оператора (для всех `U`) получат "дружбу" со всем версиями шаблонного класса (для всех `T`). Возможен также третий вариант - "неленивый" вариант шаблонного объявления, который несколько более громоздок, в котором "дружба" получится только между соответствующими (по шаблонному параметру) версиями шаблонного оператора и шаблонного класса. См. по ссылкам:
[Доступ к привату через friend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511272/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-friend)
[Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641324/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Comment: В первом варианте IDE жалуется, что не может найти определение ф-ции. Не то, чтобы это плохо, шаблоны, в конце-концов, но всё же оно работает, да