# Как перегружать оператор +?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Как лучше перегружать оператор +: через friend функцию внутри класса или как inline функцию вне класса?

Класс шаблонный.

Comment: Что такое "перегружать"? Объявлять? Определять?

Comment: @AnT переопределить, я так сначала и написать, но в похожих вопросах справа везде "перегрузка", наверное, это русский вариант для overload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно такое ограничение количества вариантов. Friend-функцию можно определять и внутри, и снаружи класса. Определение снаружи класса может быть как inline, таки и не inline. Почему вдруг речь идет только о "friend функции внутри класса"? Почему при определении вне класса речь идет именно об inline?

Тем не менее:

Во-первых, без разницы. Во-вторых, зависит от того, нужен ли вам friend-доступ. Нужен или нет?

Обычно предпочитают friend-вариант даже тогда, когда friend-доступ не нужен, просто потому, что он позволяет поместить все определение перегружаемой функции внутрь класса. Кто-то считает, что в таком виде код выглядит удобочитаемее. Это так, для небольших функций.

Большие функции, по моему мнению, лучше определять вне класса. И здесь вопрос о том, будет ли функция inline и будет ли функция friend определяется посторонними факторами, специфичными для каждой функции, которые вы в своем вопросе не упомянули.

К "шаблонности" класса все это не имеет никакого отношения. С тем только замечанием, что в таком случае есть одна тонкость: объявить нешаблонную перегрузку в таком случае можно только как friend прямо в определении шаблона класса. (см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849912/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E))

Comment: Такие варианты, потому что на cppreference friend внутри, а на stackoverflow inline снаружи

Comment: вот 1 вариант https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators
вот 2 вариант https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719