# Как обратится к типу шаблонного класса из другой функции?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

```
template <class type>
class BigInteger
{
private:
    const type base = (1 << sizeof(type) * 4) - 1;
    vector<type> digits;

public:
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger<type> object);
};

istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger<type> object)
{
    string input;
    in >> input;
    for (auto i = input.rbegin(); i != input.rend(); i++)
    {
        object.digits.push_back(*i);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Ошибка: `E0020: идентификатор "type" не определен`

Как исправить ее в моем случае?

Comment: `template <class type>` перед оператор не хватает

Comment: а она не будет каким-нибудь боком тоже просить указать тип (если бы допустим у меня была обычная функция, а не перезагрузка оператора)? или все это дело автоматизируется?

Comment: Нет, потому что компилятор сможет определить `type` по второму параметру, так же, как с обычной функцией.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849917/312941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перегруженный оператор ввода у вас не является методом класса, этот оператор всего лишь дружественная функция к вашему классу, поэтому шаблон для него нужно прописывать отдельно, так как специализация функции не зависит от специализации класса и наоборот

```
template <class type>
class BigInteger
{
private:
  const type base = (1 << sizeof(type) * 4) - 1;
  vector<type> digits;

public:
  template <class type> // здесь новая строчка
  friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger<type> object);
};

template <class type>   // и здесь 
istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger<type> object)
{
  string input;
  in >> input;
  for (auto i = input.rbegin(); i != input.rend(); i++)
  {
    object.digits.push_back(*i);
  }
  return in;
}
```