# CLion не воспринимает запись вида `T const& a` при описании функции

Tags: c++, clion, const, address, code-analyst

Есть некоторый класс `Vector2<T>` с перегруженным оператором (возможно аналогичное поведение и с обычными ф-циями, но из-за непредсказуемого поведения (об этом позже) достоверно проверить не удалось):

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
    ...
    template <typename> // объявляем дружественную ф-цию шаблонной
    friend Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v);
    ...
}
```

Обращу внимание на форму записи константной ссылки - `T const& a`, а не `const T& val`. Потом это будет играть важную роль.

Но при попытке описать эту ф-цию, а именно:

```
template <typename T>
Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v)
{ ... }
```

начинается самое интересное, а именно абсолютно непредсказуемое поведение анализа кода "на лету", от подобных генераций кода при попытке автоматической реализации объявленной ф-ции:

```
template <typename> Vector2<T> operator+(Vector2 < T >

const & l_v,

Vector2<T> const& r_v

)
{
return
Vector2<T>();
}
// да-да, именно в таком виде, со всеми отступами
```

до категоричного отказа анализировать код, подчёркивая каждое второе слово красным цветом.

В целом, иногда (очень редко), CLion воспринимает всё правильно, но через время снова начинает деградировать.

А теперь к `T const& a`. Дело в том, что если поменять именно в **описании** ф-ции запись на `const T& a`, то всё будет работать более чем нормально. Вид записи в объявлении ф-ции никак не влияет.

---

Безусловно, можно было бы просто перейти на запись вида `const T& a`, да и код-то компилируется, и это лишь визуальная помощь от данной IDE, но я бы не стал писать этот вопрос, если бы не хотел решить эту проблему, поэтому хотелось бы понять, как это возможно сделать.

---

P.S.
CLion версии 2018.1, но также проверялось на 2018.1.6, на другом устройстве, где результат был таким же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в функции и левый операнд и правый имеют тип класса, то такую функцию другом обьявить бессмысленно.

Во вторых, если работа ыункции никак не связана с состоянием обьекта, и результатом функции является совершенно другой обьект, то вообше лучше избавить интерфейс класса от этой функции и определить ее отдельно (но  в одном модуле). Например:

```
class Integer {
    int k;
public:
    Integer(int n = 0) : k(n){}
    //модификаторы
    //т.е. мы изменяем состояние обьекта *this
    Integer& operator +=(const Integer& r_v)
    {        
        k += r_v.k;
        return *this;
    }
    //...
    //селекторы
    int get_data() const { return k; }
    // функция выдает состояние обьекта
};
// operator+ (и подобные методы) определяем вне класса
inline Integer
operator +(const Integer& l_v, const Integer& r_v)
{
    Integer t(l_v);
    t += r_v;
    return t;
}
```

Такой подход  избавляет класс от лишнего интерфейса и наиболее логичен.
И если этот подход применить в написании вашего класса, то все становится гораздо проще...

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{ 
   //...
   public:
   Vector2& operator +=(Vector2 const& r_v);

};
template <typename T>
inline Vector2<T> 
operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v) {...}
```

Answer (score 5):

Дружественной вы объявили какую-то странную функцию

```
template <typename>
friend Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v);
```

У этой функции есть неименованный шаблонный параметр, который нигде не используется в сигнатуре функции. Т.е. вы объявили

```
template <typename U>
friend Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v);
```

(я просто дал имя `U` вашему безымянному параметру).

При этом, например, для класса `Vector2<int>` другом будет

```
template <typename U>
friend Vector2<int> operator +(Vector2<int> const& l_v, Vector2<int> const& r_v);
```

Зачем вы ввели этот ненужный параметр - не ясно.

К функции, определенной вами ниже

```
template <typename T>
Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v)
{ ... }
```

ваше объявление никакого отношения не имеет. Здесь у вас параметр шаблона прямо влияет на сигнатуру функции. Это определение другом вашего класса не является. Это мешанина, наверное, и сбивает с толку анализатор кода.

> А теперь к `T const& a`. Дело в том, что если поменять именно в описании ф-ции запись на `const T& a`, то всё будет работать более чем нормально.

Нет. Ничего работать нормально не будет. Как я сказал выше, ваша функция другом класса не является, со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

---

О том, как правильно объявлять шаблонных друзей, тут уже не раз писалось
[Перегрузка шаблонных операторов с разделением на описание и имплементацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849912/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)
[Доступ к привату через friend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511272/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-friend)
[Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641324/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Вы, по-видимому, пытались реализовать именно

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
    ...
    template <typename U> // объявляем дружественную ф-цию шаблонной
    friend Vector2<U> operator +(Vector2<U> const& l_v, Vector2<U> const& r_v);
    ...
};
```

но почему вы решили, что этот вариант можно "сократить" до вашего - не ясно.

Также вы можете обойтись вообще без дополнительной шаблонности вашего оператора, но при этом его придется определять прямо в классе

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
    ...
    friend Vector2<T> operator +(Vector2<T> const& l_v, Vector2<T> const& r_v)
    {
      // Определение придется писать прямо сюда
    }
    ...
};
```

ибо С++ не предоставляет синтаксиса для определения такого оператора за пределами класса.

Comment: Но ведь дело в том, что с безымянными аргументами шаблона всё действительно работало, можете проверить. И проблема с анализом кода появилась исключительно тогда, когда я решил заменить `const T&` на `T const&`.

Comment: И дружественную ф-цию как раз таки нужно объявить шаблонной явно, но использование имён `T` и `U` раздельно, будет подразумевать, что все `Vector2<T>` будут друзьями с `Vector2<U>`, что мне не очень нужно.

Comment: @Prunkles: Что именно у вас "работало" я не знаю. Смотрите упрощенный пример, построенный по вашей схеме: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a97104432a84487 . Как видите, ничего не "работает".

Comment: @Prunkles: Ничего страшного в такой "избыточной" дружбе нет. Но если вы хотите сделать не "ленивое" объявление - то смотрите по ссылкам. Там показано, как это делается. Для этого придется добавить еще несколько предварительных объявлений.

Comment: В вашем "упрощённом примере" ошибка заключается в том, что поле x, как и вообще всё объявленное в классе, является приватным. Вот исправленная и работающая версия: coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7abd08073ede4a

Comment: @Prunkles: Разумеется, оно является приватным! Именно так мы можем проверить, правильно ли сработало friend-объявление. В вашем же варианте friend-объявление является бессмысленным - оно ничего не делает и никому не нужно. Вызывается ваша отдельная функция, не имеющая никакого отношения к friend-объявлению. Зачем вы тогда вообще делали это friend-объявление? Зачем вам вообще "дружба", если у вас все и так публично доступно? Выкиньте его нафиг, и забудьте об этой проблеме: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4af42b7f7b40840